# Saving to DataBase using OleDB

Tags: c#, database, save, oledb

Im having a lot of trouble understanding OLEDB, im particularly struggling to get information to save to the database this is my current code to attempt to save:

Note: i can load the information absolutely fine, and when i run this function my information appears in my listBox however upon closing the application it hasnt saved.

If you could help explain the problem that would be great

```
void Insert_New_Log(int startfloor, int endfloor, string currentAction)
    {
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(dbconnection);
        OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand(dbcommand, conn);
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(comm);
        OleDbCommandBuilder builder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter);
       // adapter.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand();

        conn.Open();


        adapter.Fill(ds, "ElevatorTable");

        conn.Close();



        DataRow newRow = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
        newRow["ID"] = 0;
        newRow["Date1"] = dateAndTime;
        newRow["StartingFloor"] = startfloor;
        newRow["EndFloor"] = endfloor;
        newRow["Action"] = currentAction;

        ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(newRow);

        DataSet dataSetChanges = ds.GetChanges();

        try
        {
            adapter.Update(dataSetChanges, "ElevatorTable");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }

        ds.AcceptChanges();



        //update Visible list

        dbListBox.Items.Clear();
        foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            dbListBox.Items.Add(row["ID"] + "\t" + row["Date1"] + "\t" + row["StartingFloor"] + "\t" + row["EndFloor"] + "\t" + " (" + row["Action"] + ")");
        }

    }
```

ive since put a write line in and found this exception.
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' in System.Data.dll
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E14): Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdatedRowStatusErrors(RowUpdatedEventArgs rowUpdatedEvent, BatchCommandInfo[] batchCommands, Int32 commandCount)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdatedRowStatus(RowUpdatedEventArgs rowUpdatedEvent, BatchCommandInfo[] batchCommands, Int32 commandCount)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Update(DataRow[] dataRows, DataTableMapping tableMapping)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdateFromDataTable(DataTable dataTable, DataTableMapping tableMapping)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Update(DataSet dataSet, String srcTable)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Update(DataSet dataSet)
   at Elevator.Form1.Insert_New_Log(Int32 startfloor, Int32 endfloor, String currentAction) in C:\Users\Brads\Desktop\Elevator\Elevator\Form1.cs:line 197

Comment: Still figuring this out, cant find anything related online

Answer (score 1):

you have closed the connection after filling the adapter. You need to either leave the connection open or re-open it.

`adapter.Fill(ds, "ElevatorTable");
conn.Close();`

Follow this by
`conn.Open();`

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you reply with the exception details please?

Comment: im not getting an error at all its just simply not saving the data

Comment: Check if any of your parameters are null. I think there is an issue using the .GetChanges(); with MS Access databases. As the other answer suggests, I would split out your INSERT statement into a SQL statement as this is a simple query.

Answer (score 0):

Does the user you have setup in the adapter have write permissions in the SQL database? Also you closed your connection before the update statement that will need to be open in order to write back.

```
void Insert_New_Log(int startfloor, int endfloor, string currentAction)
{
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(dbconnection);
    OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand(dbcommand, conn);
    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(comm);
    OleDbCommandBuilder builder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter);
   // adapter.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand();

    conn.Open();


    adapter.Fill(ds, "ElevatorTable");        

    DataRow newRow = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
    newRow["ID"] = 0;
    newRow["Date1"] = dateAndTime;
    newRow["StartingFloor"] = startfloor;
    newRow["EndFloor"] = endfloor;
    newRow["Action"] = currentAction;

    ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(newRow);

    DataSet dataSetChanges = ds.GetChanges();
    ds.AcceptChanges();

    try
    {
        adapter.Update(dataSetChanges, "ElevatorTable");

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
    finally { conn.Close(); }

    //update Visible list

    dbListBox.Items.Clear();
    foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        dbListBox.Items.Add(row["ID"] + "\t" + row["Date1"] + "\t" + row["StartingFloor"] + "\t" + row["EndFloor"] + "\t" + " (" + row["Action"] + ")");
    }

}
```

Comment: how would i check if they have write permissions? thanks.

Comment: Go to the user security settings in the SQL server and check what his membership is DB_Onwer, DB_Datawriter, DB_DataReader, etc.. he has to at least have Datawriter and Datareader.

Comment: its a microsoft access db, its just for a school project. so everything is stored on my machine

Comment: Also you should really consider breaking out your read and update statements to separate methods for reusability.

Comment: could you elaborate please? Im still quite a novice